# Swift UIDatePicker: can you specify a color for an individual date on the calendar (accessibility contrast problem)

Tags: swift, accessibility, uidatepicker

I am using a UIDatePicker in inline mode, in an app that has both dark and light mode.

I have specified a light blue AccentColor for dark mode, which works well for all other components. But for the calendar, I end up with a problem when the selected day is the actual date, because it gets rendered with white on light blue, hence not having enough contrast to meet accessibility requirements.

I think this is a bug in the date picker, because in light mode, today's date changes color when selected, so that it is rendered in white while all other dates are rendered in dark gray. I nevertheless need to do something to fix that - is
there a way to override the color of the text for an individual date?

[image]

Comment: Not as far as I know. Something like [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) can easily solve this issue though.

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't look like an option unfortunately. We have to support screen readers, voice control and larger text too (etc), so we can't consider a third party library unless they state on the record that they are fully compliant with all assistive tech...